# 'module' object has no attribute 'isna'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a df called `batch_df` and I added 'as_percentage' into the df. If hours is Nan, then set as_percentage as 0. The code ran fine in PyCharm but when I ran it on the terminal, I got this error: Please help!

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/vic_ong/dev/resource-management/generateBatch.py", line 166, in 
>       main()
>
> File "/Users/vic_ong/dev/resource-management/generateBatch.py", line 51, in main
>
> batch_df.loc[pd.isna(batch_df['hours']) == False, 'as_percentage'] = 0
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isna'

Edit -- My code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import lib
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
# get directories
batchInputDir = '/Users/vic_ong/dev/resource-management/data/input/batchUpload'


def main():
# start timer
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# walk into every csv file in batchUpload and concatenate them into one df
list_ = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(batchInputDir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(batchInputDir, file), index_col=None, header=0)
            list_.append(df)
batch_df = pd.concat(list_)
batch_df = batch_df.dropna(how='all')
batch_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
# clean data frame
# rename to standardized column names
batch_df.rename(columns={'Resource Name': 'name',
                         'Hours': 'hours'},
                inplace=True)
# determine if value given was a percentage
batch_df['as_percentage'] = 1
batch_df.loc[pd.isna(batch_df['hours']) == False, 'as_percentage'] = 0
print batch_df.head

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

batch_df sample:

`name  hours  as_percentage
vic   Nan      1
vic1  Nan      1`

Comment: You need to post the rest of your code. What is `pd`? It is not evident from your snippet. Is it what you renamed the `panda` module?

Comment: Update your Pandas. It's probably out of date.

Comment: @robobrobro yes, it is the pandas module that I renamed. I just added the rest of my code.

Comment: I don't know pandas, but did you mean to call `pd.isnan`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The `isna` alias for `isnull` was only added in version 0.21](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/whatsnew.html#na-naming-changes) (0.22 is the latest release as of Jan 2018); on 0.20 and earlier, it doesn't exist; you have to use the older (and still supported) `isnull` name instead. Either update your `pandas` install, or use the older name.

Comment: Thanks! It was because my pandas module was out of date. It worked fine after I updated pandas :)

Comment: 0.21 isn't quite the latest release any more; [0.22 came out a few weeks ago](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/whatsnew.html).

Comment: @user2357112: Ah, accidentally skipped straight to previous version links. Fixing.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.isna = pandas.isnull` does it for me as a workaround

Comment: This is brilliant. In my case Seaborn boxplot was throwing this error possibly due to version mismatch. This gives a quick workaround before we fix the root cause