# TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported ... when trying to remove nan float type from dictionary value

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, dictionary, nan

```
d = {'E1': ['C',
        'Me',
        'Lans',
        nan,
        '3050',
        '55901',
        nan,
        nan,
        '2011-09-05 00:00:00',
        '3050-09-02 00:00:00',
        '2011-09-05 00:00:00',
        '3050-09-02 00:00:00'],
 'E2': ['Can',
        'Mar',
        'Horns',
        '26D',
        '1001',
        '14086',
        nan,
        '(100) 300-2345',
        '1001-09-02 00:00:00',
        '0100-09-02 00:00:00',
        '2011-19-26 00:00:00',
        '1001-09-02 00:00:00',
        '0100-09-02 00:00:00',
        '2011-19-26 00:00:00']}
```

I have the following dict `d` and I want to get rid of the `nan`. According to [remove entries with nan values in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035431/remove-entries-with-nan-values-in-python-dictionary) I can use the following to do so

```
for k,v in d.items():
    if np.isnan(v[1]):
        d.pop(k)
print(d)
```

But I get an error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

So I looked at ['module' object has no attribute 'isna'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313035/module-object-has-no-attribute-isna) and it suggests using

`pd.isnull` instead of `np.isna` but that doesnt work either. So I wonder, how do I get rid of the `nan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `isinstance`

**Ex:**

```
d = {k: [i for i in v if isinstance(i, str)] for k,v in d.items()}
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'E1': ['C',
        'Me',
        'Lans',
        '3050',
        '55901',
        '2011-09-05 00:00:00',
        '3050-09-02 00:00:00',
        '2011-09-05 00:00:00',
        '3050-09-02 00:00:00'],
 'E2': ['Can',
        'Mar',
        'Horns',
        '26D',
        '1001',
        '14086',
        '(100) 300-2345',
        '1001-09-02 00:00:00',
        '0100-09-02 00:00:00',
        '2011-19-26 00:00:00',
        '1001-09-02 00:00:00',
        '0100-09-02 00:00:00',
        '2011-19-26 00:00:00']}
```